# Asynchronous creation of FeatureClass with BackgroundWorker failed

Tags: arcobjects

I use `BackgroundWorker` to create asynchronous class elements. When running to

```cs
IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pFeatureWorksapce.CreateFeatureClass(pFileName, pFields, null, null, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "Shape", "");
```

the form of AppCrash is popped up. The error code is `c0000005`.
When I no longer use `BackgroundWorker` to create a `FeatureClass`. This method is normal.

```cs
mBackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
mBackgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(mBackgroundWorker_DoWork);

private void mBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    FeatureClassCreatorParams pParams = new FeatureClassCreatorParams();
    IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = CreateShapefile(pParams);
}
public IFeatureClass CreateShapefile(FeatureClassCreatorParams param)
{
    if (param == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("FeatureClassCreatorParams is null");
    }
    param.Verify();
    List<FieldClassInfo> pFieldList = ReadXml(param.XmlPath);
    IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = CreateShpFileStructure(param.SavePath, pFieldList, param.GeometryType, param.SpatialReference, param.HasZ);
    return pFeatureClass;
}
private IFeatureClass CreateShpFileStructure(string fileName, List<FieldClassInfo> fields, esriGeometryType geoType, ISpatialReference spatialReference, bool hasZ)
{
    string pFloder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
    string pFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
    if (!Directory.Exists(pFloder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pFloder);
    }
    IWorkspaceFactory pWorkspaceFactory = new ShapefileWorkspaceFactory();
    IFeatureWorkspace pFeatureWorksapce = pWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(pFloder, 0) as IFeatureWorkspace;
    IFields pFields = new FieldsClass();
    IFieldsEdit pFieldsEdit = pFields as IFieldsEdit;

        // 添加几何字段
    IField pShapeField = new FieldClass();
    IFieldEdit pShapeFieldEdit = pShapeField as IFieldEdit;
    pShapeFieldEdit.Name_2 = "Shape";
    pShapeFieldEdit.Type_2 = esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGeometry;

    IGeometryDef pGeometryDef = new GeometryDefClass();
    IGeometryDefEdit pGeometryDefEdit = pGeometryDef as IGeometryDefEdit;
    pGeometryDefEdit.GeometryType_2 = geoType;
    pGeometryDefEdit.HasZ_2 = hasZ;
    pGeometryDefEdit.SpatialReference_2 = spatialReference;
    pShapeFieldEdit.GeometryDef_2 = pGeometryDef;
    pFieldsEdit.AddField(pShapeField);

        //foreach (FieldClassInfo field in fields)
        //{
        //    IField pField = new FieldClass();
        //    IFieldEdit pFieldEdit = pField as IFieldEdit;
        //    pFieldEdit.Name_2 = field.Name;
        //    pFieldEdit.Type_2 = field.FieldType;
        //    pFieldEdit.AliasName_2 = field.Caption;
        //    pFieldEdit.Length_2 = field.Length;
        //    pFieldsEdit.AddField(pField);
        //}

    // Throw Error:appCrash
    IFeatureClass pFeatureClass = pFeatureWorksapce.CreateFeatureClass(pFileName, pFields, null, null, esriFeatureType.esriFTSimple, "Shape", "");
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using Activator.CreateInstance for your workspacefactory? http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISengine/dotnet/c778d2bb-eb36-4793-9c89-20795811c5eb.htm#Shapefile

Comment: What is the result if, instead of making a BackgroundWorker, you just created and started a new Thread? Be sure to set the ApartmentState to STA.

Comment: I want to create a shapefile with BackgroundWorker

Comment: But I want to know if the issue is related to specifically the BackgroundWorker thread or any alternative thread, this helps get to the root of your issue. Furthermore, any new thread in which you are using ArcObjects should be an STA thread, which BackgroundWorker does not support.

Comment: If you are using ArcGIS desktop objects then yes, your problem is because of the background worker. ArcGIS is a *single thread application*, the objects are not thread safe. This does not mean you can't use multiple threads just that you can't pass objects over the thread boundaries... instead of BackgroundWorker use system.threading.thread with ApartmentState of STA, create a new instance as @KirkKuykendall indicates then **only pass non-Esri objects over the threads**; there are some exceptions to this rule, but that's another topic in itself born of a thousand facepalm moments!

Comment: Search for "threads in isolation" for more info.